# REGEX to find and replace IMG elements

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm looking for a regular expression to remove a given (x)HTML tag from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116403/im-looking-for-a-regular-expression-to-remove-a-given-xhtml-tag-from-a-string)

I have a long HTML file and I need to remove all the `<img />` tags inside it and all the `<a><img /></a>` anchors.

What I'm thinking of is writing a PHP script that does the job. But each image and link has different number attributes so I don't know how I can do this neatly. Any help would be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, this is the final solution that I was looking for.

```
$text = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\><img[^>]+\><\/a>\n/i", "", $text);

$text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
```

Comment: It's easy to construct valid HTML that makes those regexes misbehave.

Comment: Although it is not quite easy, still the regexes are useful for use in your own page or something you (or someone near you) control.

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOM parser such as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 1):

try
     `<img[^>]+/>`

Comment: This command line removed my img tags, leaving a couple of right angle brackets, which were no problem for me:`perl -pi'~' -e "s/<img[^>]+/>/g" webpage.html`