# Regular expression for removing HTML tags from a string

Tags: java, html, regex, jsp

I am looking for a regular expression to removing all HTML tags from a string in JSP.

Example 1

```
sampleString = "test string <i>in italics</i> continues";
```

Example 2

```
sampleString = "test string <i>in italics";
```

Example 3

```
sampleString = "test string <i";
```

The HTML tag might be complete, partial (without closing tag) or without proper starting tag (missing closing angle bracket in 3rd example) itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm looking for a regular expression to remove a given (x)HTML tag from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116403/im-looking-for-a-regular-expression-to-remove-a-given-xhtml-tag-from-a-string) You probably missed the list of many previous related questions while typing the title of your own question :)

Comment: Will that satisfy the third example also?

Comment: By adding a single question mark at the right spot, yes.

Comment: Standard warning: html cannot be parsed with regular expressions, look here for kicks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Just keep in mind he's asking how to remove tags, not to parse them. If you just want to strip tags, I'm pretty sure that can be done with regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

Case 3 is not possible with regex or a parser. It might represent legitimate content. So forget it.

As to the concrete question which covers cases 1 and 2, just use a HTML parser. My favourite is [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

That's it. It has by the way also a [HTML cleaner](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer), if that is what you're *actually* after.

Since you're using JSP, you could also just use JSTL `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()` to avoid that user-controlled HTML input get inlined among your HTML (which may thus open XSS holes).

```
<c:out value="${bean.property}" />
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

HTML tags will then not be interpreted, but just displayed as plain text.

Comment: Nice solution to the problem. Thanks. I used the Cleaner, as it is very customizable through the [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
<\/?font(\s\w+(\=\".*\")?)*\>
```

I used this little gem about a week ago to strip a variety of 12-year-old html tags, and it worked pretty great. Just replace '`font`' with whatever tag you're looking for, or with `\w*` to get rid of all of them.

**Edit** removed '?' from the end of my string after realizing that could remove non-tag data from a file.  Basically, this will consistently find case 1 and 2, but if used with case 3 (with the '?' appended to the end of the regex), caution should be used to ensure what is removed is a tag.